# CLOSE: - Suggested redirection to another group not always appearing

Tags: discussion

I just noticed going through the close queue that the selection to redirect the given question to another group is sometimes missing.  Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a question has already been migrated once, it cannot be migrated again except by a moderator.